# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in VS while deploying multidimensional project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, olap

When I try to deploy new empty multidimensional project in "Visual Studio 2017 Data Tools" I get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
However I see the new databse in Analysis Services via SSMS. Then I try to fill my project with data (AdventureWorksDW) and deploy but that error occurs again and no data loaded to db.

- SQL Server 2017
- Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Without more details is not possible to say. It could be a duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Steve what details? I click "deploy" and then the error occurs. 
Create new project -> deploy. That's all.

Comment: So it is an error in the tools, not in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If someone runs across this (happened to me in VS2022)
Check your .sqlproj file and ensure you have the xmlns defined correctly:

`<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

This is what fixed the deploy problem for me.
see [sql-server-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/applications/iot-smart-grid/Db/Db.sqlproj)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had `x64` build platform configuration and I had to set the sql project to `Any CPU` platform